# How to put margin on wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper `div` which has 100% width in size without `float` properties how I can implement `margin-top:-30px` any solution? Please look at this example.

```css
.slider_container{
  width:100%;
  margin-top:-30px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">

</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `margin-top: -30px;`? I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @HashemQolami please check my example.

Comment: I don't see anything within your example. What is the expected behavior? How should it look like? The div *is* affected by the negative margin at the moment.

Comment: When you apply `margin-top:-30px;` with `width:100%;` margin will never work so my question is what should I do to implement negative margin on top.

Comment: The margin ***is*** being applied (you could check it out by devtools). Please expand on `margin will never work`.

Comment: To chime in: What has `margin-top` to do with `width`? They don't influence each other. Your example is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please add overflow: hidden on wrapper then it will work